# Randomized Autoclicker C++ using one key for on/off

Tags: c++

I have been attempting to write a cpp autoclicker using header `<windows.h>` but it isn't working the best. The code works fine and all, but its extremely annoying to turn off as it requires a millisecond click, nothing longer, if I hold that shortcut for too long, it turns back on again. Any suggestions for improvements?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
int counti;
void menu()
{
    cout << "Press 'Ctrl + Tab' to enable and Press 'Ctrl + Tab' to disable randomised autoclicker\n";
}

void clicker()
{
    bool click = false; //sets click to false
    int n;

    while (true)
    {
        while (1) {
            n = rand() % 125;
            if (n > 75)break;
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_TAB)) //if Ctrl + Tab is pressed
        {
            counti++;
            if (counti % 2 == 1)click = true; //Shortcut pressed once and it activates
            else if (counti % 2 == 0)click = false; //Shortcut pressed again and it deactivates
        }
        if (click == true) // if click = true it will press the mouse button down and up really fast
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            cout << n << endl;
            Sleep(n); //random speed here
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    menu();
    clicker();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` is very peculiar. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same hotkey to turn on and off. Use a different key.

Comment: Out of convenience, I want to use the same hotkey.